# AT the death of ...or BY the death of

Tags: prepositions

There is this sentence "the staff members were shocked **at** the death of their boss"

I am wondering is it possible to say "the staff members were shocked **by** the death of their boss"

If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible, and more common in current English - see [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shocked+at%2C+shocked+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)